# Exclude VCL Styles from styling Dialog / ShowMessage borders

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe7, vcl-styles

Is there any way to exclude VCL Styles from styling a system dialogs' border.

Sepecifically a dialog that is shown by calling MessageDlg or ShowMessage.

I read some articles on "The Road To Delphi" (which is an excellent site btw) but couldn't find the answer.

Here is what i want to achieve:

Now (Carbon Style with styled borders):

[image: now]

Goal (Carbon Style with standard windows borders):

[image]

I still want to have styled controls but no styled border.

Removing `seBorder` from the parent forms StyleElements doesn't do the trick.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should rephrase your statement that you already tried setting the *parent* forms style. The way it is written has already misled two people. Also, what dialogs exactly are you interested in, because a great number of dialogs do not even support styling without 3rd party units.

Comment: I rephrased the first sentences

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but please also edit what you have tried. 'Setting' is the wrong word and misleading when you removed 'seBorder' from StyleElements. I suggest: `Removing `seBorder` from the **parent** forms `StyleElements` doesn't do the trick.`

Comment: It'll be interesting to hear the answer, but the goal screenshot looks a bit weird and ugly to me. Mixing a custom style with a random system style (who knows what users installed) doesn't sound like a good plan to me. In fact I've had so many user complaints because of skins that I now tend to shy away from them. The default windows styles might be boring, but they're well tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MessageDlg()` and `ShowMessage()` are Delphi VCL functions. They dynamically create a Delphi `TForm` and display that, so you do not have a chance to customise it. However, you can use `CreateMessageDialog()` instead to create the same `TForm`, then modify its style elements as needed, and then show it. For instance:

```
function DoMessageDlgPosHelp(MessageDialog: TForm; X, Y: Integer): Integer;
begin
  with MessageDialog do
    try
      if X >= 0 then Left := X;
      if Y >= 0 then Top := Y;
      if (Y < 0) and (X < 0) then Position := poScreenCenter;
      Result := ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;

procedure ShowStyledMessage(const Msg: string; const StyleElements: TStyleElements);
var
  Form: TForm;
begin
  Form := CreateMessageDialog(Msg, mtCustom, [mbOK]);
  Form.StyleElements := StyleElements;
  DoMessageDlgPosHelp(Form, -1, -1);
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
ShowStyledMessage('Some text', [seFont, seClient]);
```

And the dialog looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Above solution will not work for message dialogs called by 3rd party code. Any ShowMessage will result in fully styled form.

Comment: @Dalija That's right. Also any system dialogs, ie calls to MessageBox or TaskDialogIndirect.

Answer (score 4):

To have styled form without borders you have to remove `seBorder` from form's `StyleElements` property.

```
  StyleElements := [seFont, seClient];
```

[image: From form designer]

But you have to set that property for each and every form. If I understood you correctly you want to show message dialog with Windows border. In that case setting `StyleElements` property for form that invokes `ShowMessage` will have no effect on dialog box, because that is completely new form.

What you have to do is to somehow set `StyleElements` property for dialog form that Delphi creates out of your reach. To do that you have to create your own form `StyleHook` and replace `TFormStyleHook` registered for all forms.

Just add following unit in your project and all forms will have Windows border, without the need to set it explicitly for every form.

```
unit WinBorder;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms;

type
  TWinBorderFormStyleHook = class(TFormStyleHook)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AControl: TWinControl); override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TWinBorderFormStyleHook.Create(AControl: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited;
  OverridePaintNC := false;
end;

procedure TWinBorderFormStyleHook.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.Msg = CM_VISIBLECHANGED then
    begin
      if (Control is TCustomForm) and (seBorder in TCustomForm(Control).StyleElements) then
        TCustomForm(Control).StyleElements := [seFont, seClient];
    end;
end;

initialization

  TCustomStyleEngine.UnRegisterStyleHook(TCustomForm, TFormStyleHook);
  TCustomStyleEngine.UnRegisterStyleHook(TForm, TFormStyleHook);
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TCustomForm, TWinBorderFormStyleHook);
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TForm, TWinBorderFormStyleHook);

finalization

  TCustomStyleEngine.UnRegisterStyleHook(TCustomForm, TWinBorderFormStyleHook);
  TCustomStyleEngine.UnRegisterStyleHook(TForm, TWinBorderFormStyleHook);
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TCustomForm, TFormStyleHook);
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TForm, TFormStyleHook);

end.
```

Comment: Plus 1 Nice solution conforming to the spirit of styles. I removed now irrelevant comments.

Comment: An important thing to note is that this unit must be used *after* the `Vcl.Forms` unit. (+1). If it were up to me, I'd make this the accepted answer.

Comment: @JerryDodge Since this unit itself uses Vcl.Forms it does not matter where you put it in uses clause.